# `yield` keyword shows parse error for this keyword

Tags: php, yield

Please consider the following code. I have no idea how the `yield` keyword works. Can anybody describe why the `$this` produce an error with `yield`.

```
class Collection {

    /**
     *  Dependency injection container.
     *
     *  @var Container
     */
    protected $_Container = null;

    /**
     *  Constructor.
     *
     *  @param Container $Container Dependency injection container
     *      used to build providers.
     */
    public function __construct(Container $Container) {
        $this->_Container = $Container;
    }

    // ...

    /**
     *  Finds providers of the given url.
     *
     *  @todo Use PHP generators to yield providers.
     *  @param string $url An url which may be extracted.
     *  @return array An array of Essence\Provider.
     */
    public function providers($url) {
        $filters = $this->_Container->get('filters');

        foreach ($filters as $name => $filter) {
            if ($this->_matches($filter, $url)) {
                yield $this->_Container->get($name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `yield $this->_Container->get($name);` shows parse error. which is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/test.xyz/modules/embedder/vendor/Essence/Provider/Collection.php on line 71"

It will also help if you can describe how I can write different way of the line  `yield $this->_Container->get($name);`.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which PHP Version? Generators were introduced in PHP5.5 - if you use 5.4 or older, this wouldn't work

Comment: Used php 5.6 for development.

Comment: Please read http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php

Comment: The code you posted works perfectly fine in PHP5.6 - the error must be somewhere else..

Comment: You are right. Just checked the version in cpanel. it was 5.4, once I changed to 5.6; it is working :) Thank You.

Comment: Don't change it to 5.6 - change it to the latest. 5.6 is nearly at the EOL cycle and won't get security updates in the near future

Comment: Problem is the entire site was built on php5.6, we need to upgrade the scripts before upgrade php version ...